# Looking for a non -ly word to use instead of certainly

Tags: adverbs

I'm writing a seminar on a book as a school assignment, and I need a word to replace "certainly", as in "this is certainly true", because I want to avoid using words that end in -ly.

Comment: Why would you avoid words that end in -ly?

Comment: Sure you can, no doubt.

Comment: In the context of agreeing with something that has just been said, you could try one of the following words: (for) sure, by all means, quite, indeed, of course. For emphasization, without the necessity for a preceeding statement, try: beyond doubt, beyond question,  without question, without (a) doubt. Source: google...

Comment: It's not advice I always follow myself, but it is nevertheless good advice, that "certainly" or any replacement word in that phrase is already flabby writing. It's either true or it's not. Adding "certainly" (et al.) *casts doubt* on the truth, rather than affirming it.

Comment: @JEL: what if the writer wants to cast doubt, or to hedge what they're saying? Or what if writing is about more than the literal meaning of things? There are lots of ways to use words; it seems foolish to me to declare something "flabby writing" based solely on its use of an ordinary and common English word.

Comment: You could also use "_holds true_" if you are talking about an already known and proved principle or law of nature which can be applied at this point of interest.

Comment: @sumelic, those are good points, and perhaps I should've said "is already flabby" and left the "writing" out of it. Observe, however: (1) I know more about the instance than the phrase only ("writing a seminar on a book as a school assignment" not only indicates a student is doing the writing, but suggests the "certainly true" phrase will *not* be spoken by a character who is intended to be represented as something of an oaf, etc.); (2) I said it's not advice I always follow; (3) writing is *always* about more than the literal meaning. Nonetheless, 'the exact center' and similar are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding all adverbs ending in -ly, excludes the best substitutes.  I can only suggest "this is **no doubt** true", "this is **indeed** true"  or "this is **sure to be** true".

"indeed" and "no doubt" as mentioned in comments.